# Creating a security database that already exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have been developing a secure area of a website and I had it running really well.  I came back to it today to work some more on it and when I try to open `../admin/default.aspx` in my browser, I get the following message:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Cannot create file
>   'H:\PBC\PBCSite2012\App_Data\PBCData.mdf' because it already exists.
>   Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation. CREATE
>   DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check
>   related errors.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot create
>   file 'H:\PBC\PBCSite2012\App_Data\PBCData.mdf' because it already
>   exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the
>   operation. CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be
>   created. Check related errors.

The default.aspx page in the Admin folder has Login and LoginView controls.  It appears to me as if the site is trying to create the security database.  The only thing is, this has already been created and tested.  It was working previously.  So what I can't figure out:

1. why is it doing this, and
2. what can I do to correct it (other than deleting the database and starting over).

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the solution then re-building?

Comment: I got it working again.  Turned out the connection string was wrong.  Don't know why it was wrong as it worked a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have done the same steps that I did below:

1. You created a new asp.net project and it had its new web.config file
2. The new web.config has a default mdf database file name in DefaultConnection connectionString
3. You copied an old mdf database file from an old project (containing some data)
4. You modified web.config to attach the copied mdf database file
5. You forgot to modify (or remove) the Initial Catalog part of connectionString

The problem was in the last step above, when I removed Initial Catalog, it was fixed

Answer (score -1):

I am using Entity Framework in my .NET project, my connection string did NOT have `Initial Catalog=True` in it at all, I had to append `Initial Catalog=False` to stop getting this error.